# Resize Slideshow to Fill Screen

Tags: javascript, css, resize, slideshow, image-resizing

I am building a photography website with an automatic slideshow.

I'm trying to make it so that the slideshow resizes to fit the browser so that it fills the screen **leaving no white-space above or below**. I also need it to zoom the image in if the screen is the wrong ratio for the image (so that if users are on a device such as an iphone, the image still fills the screen properly).

Please view  [this website](http://www.burkardphoto.com/) for an example. Note that if you rotate your screen 90 degrees that the image zooms and remains centred to still fill the screen.

This is what I currently have (if I must I'll change the method of slideshow).

**HTML + JavaScript (in head)**

```
...
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {

            $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

            setInterval(function() { 
                $('#slideshow > div:first')
                .fadeOut(1500)
                .next()
                .fadeIn(1500)
                .end()
                .appendTo('#slideshow');
            }, 5000);

        });
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="slideshow">
        <div>
            <img src="images/slide1.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="images/slide2.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="images/slide3.jpg"/>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- end slideshow -->
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#slideshow { 

    position: relative; 

    width: 100%; 

}

#slideshow > div { 

    position: absolute; 

}
```

Thanks in advance, and sorry if it's a badly worded question or if it makes no sense.

Kieran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't make the div absolute make the img absolute . thats where you are going wrong .
Also make the image to 100% so that it would take the whole screen

**CSS:**

```
body{
 padding:0;//so that there is no white space
 margin:0;
}
#slideshow {
    display:block; 
    position: relative; 
    width: 100%; 
}
#slideshow > div > img{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    position:absolute; // here make it absolute 
}
#slideshow > div { 
 position:relative; // make it relative not necessary actually
}
```

[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bA7L5/2/)

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, thank you for clearing that up :)